# Simplifying weighted moving average calculation

Tags: python, pandas

```
accs = pd.DataFrame({'v': values[start_index:], 'w': weights[start_index:]})\
        .rolling(window=window_len, min_periods=1, method='table').apply(weighted_mean, engine='numba', raw=True)\
        .v.to_numpy()[a:b] # after .apply() we get df back with all columns being set to the same resulting sequence
```

Is it possible here to simplify that expression by removing `.v.to_numpy()` part? It's there because the `.apply(weighted_mean, engine='numba', raw=True)` returns dataframe back with all the columns set to the same resulting series. I would like to get the straight numpy array back immediately if possible.

Comment: No, `.to_numpy()` is *the straightforward* way to get a numpy array from a DataFrame/Series.

Comment: what are the rules for your moving average?